# Как спарсить цену товара на Python?

Tags: python

Всем добрый день. Пишу парсер на Python. Подскажите, как можно спарсить цену без скидки из этого магазина?
https://lenta.com/catalog/tovary-dlya-detejj/igrushki/konstruktory/konstruktor-lego-movie-poznakomtes-s-korolevojj-mnogolikojj-prekrasnojj-70824-kitajj/

Это магазин лента. Вот код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

list_with_category = []
page_link = 'https://lenta.com/catalog/bezalkogolnye-napitki/limonady-i-kvasy/limonady/napitok-bezalkogolnyjj-mirinda-refreshing-osvezh-vkus-apelsina-silnogaz-pet-rossiya-15l/'
response = requests.get(page_link)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


price_1_rub = soup.find('span', class_='sku-price__integer').get_text(strip=True)
price_1_kop = soup.find('small', class_='sku-price__fraction').get_text(strip=True)

price_2_rub = soup.find('div', class_='sku-price sku-price--primary sku-prices-block__price').find('span', class_='sku-price__integer').get_text(strip=True)
price_2_kop = soup.find('div', class_='sku-price sku-price--primary sku-prices-block__price').find('small', class_='sku-price__fraction').get_text(strip=True)


print(price_1_rub, price_1_kop, sep=',')
print('----------------------')
print(price_2_rub, price_2_kop, sep=',')
print('----------------------')
```

А если вставить ссылку от другого товара, то работает.
Как парсить не иероглифы, а числа? Заранее большое спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не иероглифы, а спецсимвол непрерывного пробела, просто сделайте в коде его замену на пробел

Comment: Могли бы сказать как его заменить?

Comment: Функцией replace: `price_1_rub = price_1_rub.replace("&nbsp;", " ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто используйте функцию `replace`:

```
price_1_rub = price_1_rub.replace("&nbsp;", " ")
```

Comment: Всё равно возникает ошибка

Comment: @Олег, хотите сказать, что замена `&nbsp;` не помогла и в переменной этот спец-символ остался?

Comment: Запустите и поймёте

Comment: @Олег, если вы про ваш следующий вопрос, то это не связанно с текущим. `None` вернется из `find` если элемент не найден, а `None.get_text(strip=True)` вызовет ошибку. Однако, `replace` вызывается после `get_text`, соответственно, не иметт отношение к той ошибке. А та ошибка могла возникнуть, например, если тот сайт решил бороться с ботом, и например, вернуть капчу. Кст, пожалуйста, если у вас возникают ошибки, то нужно так и писать, добавляя текст и строку места возникновения. Да и у меня она могла и не возникнуть, если я прав насчет сайта и его противодействия вашему скрипту